# React Bootstrap: How to use all columns for small devices and fixed width for medium devices

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have a React Bootstrap column which right now looks this way:

```
<Col xs={12} md={3}>
```

I want to modify it so it has a fixed width of 500 for medium devices and tried to apply

`className="d-flex flex-md-grow-0 flex-md-shrink-0"` but that doesn't seem to work. Also I don't know how to set `flex-basis` to apply the 500px width or do I have to combine it with `w-500`?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set an css max-width at col-md-

```js
const Grid = ReactBootstrap.Grid;
const Row = ReactBootstrap.Row;
const Col = ReactBootstrap.Col;


const Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return { showModal: false };
    },
  
    render() {

        
        return (
          <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="hello" xs={12} md={12}>
                     Hello
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
});
 
ReactDOM.render(
 <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.col-md-12 {
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.5/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.28.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Any chance to do it inline: `<Col xs={12} md={12} style={{ /* Here? */}}>`?